# HttpWebRequest Error: 503 server unavailable

Tags: c#, https, httpwebrequest

I'm using HttpWebRequest and I get error when execute GetResponse().

I using this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Uri myUri = new Uri("http://www.google.com/sorry/?continue=http://www.google.com/search%3Fq%3Dyamaha");
        // Create a 'HttpWebRequest' object for the specified url. 
        HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myUri);
        // Set the user agent as if we were a web browser
        myHttpWebRequest.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.0.4) Gecko/20060508 Firefox/1.5.0.4";

        HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        var stream = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
        var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        var html = reader.ReadToEnd();
        // Release resources of response object.
        myHttpWebResponse.Close();

        textBox1.Text = html;
    }
```

Comment: Did you get the same error when requesting the URL in a browser or a tool like curl?

Comment: That looks like a decidedly strange URL to fetch programmatically. Any reason for it?

Comment: http://www.google.com/sorry/ returns a 503.  If you are trying to automate a large number of queries to Google, you may get that URL.  But as Jon Skeet asked, why are you submitting requests to that URL in the first place? See http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=86640

Comment: Google detects that you are trying to fetch a URL that is not meant to be fetched programmatically. Why are you fetching that URL?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The server really returns a 503 HTTP status code. However, it also returns a response body along with the 503 error condition (the contents you see in a browser if you open that URL).

You have access to the response in the exception's `Response` property (in case there's a 503 response, the exception that's raised is a `WebException`, which has a `Response` property). you need to catch this exception and handle it properly

Concretely, your code could look like this:

```
string html;

try
{
    var myUri = new Uri("http://www.google.com/sorry/?continue=http://www.google.com/search%3Fq%3Dyamaha");
    // Create a 'HttpWebRequest' object for the specified url. 
    var myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myUri);
    // Set the user agent as if we were a web browser
    myHttpWebRequest.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.0.4) Gecko/20060508 Firefox/1.5.0.4";

    var myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    var stream = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
    var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    html = reader.ReadToEnd();
    // Release resources of response object.
    myHttpWebResponse.Close();
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    using(var sr = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()))
        html = sr.ReadToEnd();
}

textBox1.Text = html;
```

Comment: @Ainun Nuha I am trying to translate text from Thailand to English but I am facing similar issue. I get exception at GetResponse() which is being catched in catch() block. But it send HTML of complete page with content "Web Page Blocked". How can I get the string translated into english.