# C# support by web hosting services

Tags: c#, php, mysql, asp.net, hosting

I am developing a C# application that communicate to a MySQL server via php using .Net System.Net.WebRequest. It worked fine until I switched my web hosting service to BlueHost. My application no longer works, instead, I get the error message "WebException: The remote server returned an error: (503) Service Unavailable.". I contacted BlueHost tech support and was told that they do not support C#.

I didn't know that System.Net.WebRequest has to be "supported" by the web server?! I am pretty baffled. I will probably switch back to my old hosting service, but I would like to know more about the issue.

Can somebody please explain this to me just for the peace of mind? Thanks a lot!

Jason

Comment: u need a asp.net windows host

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to reach your PHP web app using a web browser - then you should be able to make a web request from your C# app.

You can try reading the Response property from the WebException - it may give you more information about what went wrong. See this answer for an example on how to do that https://stackoverflow.com/a/10107490/138392.

Furthermore, is your C# app sitting behind a web proxy? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18013509/138392 for a way to force the HttpWebRequest to use your default proxy settings.

Also, have you tried setting the UserAgent property of the WebRequest? Try:

```
request.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)";
```

Personally, I prefer using the [WebClient](http://www.dotnetperls.com/webclient) or [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) classes when making web requests as a lot of the boilerplate code is abstracted away. The [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org) library is also really useful when working with web APIs.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. The information is in deep in WebException.Response. I will explore the other classes you have mentioned.